# Using Pax exam without using Maven

Tags: maven, pax-exam

For a project I need to try to run tests in an osgi environment, but i haven't the possibility to use Maven for it, so I find it very hard to use as I am not even able to find sources to use Pax exam, for start...

Thanks for trying to help me.
Have a good day

Answer (score 2):

The sources for Pax Exam are here: https://github.com/ops4j/org.ops4j.pax.exam2.

`pax-exam-link-assembly` can be used to provision all dependencies of Pax Exam itself in OSGi mode when Maven is not available.

You'll have to manage all other dependencies on your own, and you can't use `mavenBundle()` options or `mvn:` URLs, obviously.